# Upload file larger than 2Gb by restsharp

Tags: c#, httprequest, restsharp

i have to upload file larger then 2GB.

I want to use restsharp but i got error "Stream was too long".
It's possible to do it with restharp or i should use other library?

```
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            client.ThrowOnDeserializationError = true;
            client.ConfigureWebRequest(x => x.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("X-Auth-Token", token);
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");

            const int chunkSize = 1024; // read the file by chunks of 1KB
            using (var file = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                int bytesRead;
                var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
                while ((bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    request.AddFileBytes("file", buffer, filePath);
                }
            }


            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Answer (score 1):

If we inspect the project on GitHub, the text "Stream was too long" does not exist in the project https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp

Instead it is typically an exception for memory stream which have this max size limitation of 2 GB, Unfortunately the RestSharp use a MemoryStream in one method, but you should be able to use the other:

```
//RestSharp.RestRequest.AddFileBytes:     will not work
/// <inheritdoc />
public IRestRequest AddFileBytes(
    string name,
    byte[] bytes,
    string filename,
    string contentType = "application/x-gzip"
)
{
    long length = bytes.Length;

    return AddFile(
        new FileParameter
        {
            Name          = name,
            FileName      = filename,
            ContentLength = length,
            ContentType   = contentType,
            Writer = s =>
            {
                using var file = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(bytes));

                file.BaseStream.CopyTo(s);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

working directly with a byte array should work though so use AddFile instead of AddFileBytes

```
//RestSharp.RestRequest.AddFile  

/// <inheritdoc />
public IRestRequest AddFile(string name, byte[] bytes, string fileName, string contentType = null)
    => AddFile(FileParameter.Create(name, bytes, fileName, contentType));

public static FileParameter Create(string name, byte[] data, string filename, string? contentType)
    => new() {
            Writer        = s => s.Write(data, 0, data.Length),
            FileName      = filename,
            ContentType   = contentType,
            ContentLength = data.LongLength,
            Name          = name
        };
```

So you see the latter use the base stream class and this doesn't have that limitation as for instance FileStream deriviate can handle larger

Comment: You could of cause take the easy way out and file it as a bug on the project and hope somebody will fix it for you instead :)